# PHP cant update SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound

Tags: php, mysql

Table structure:

```
ex_id   int(11)  
ex_fecha    date     
ex_nombre   varchar(100)     
ex_apaterno varchar(100)     
ex_materno  varchar(100)     
ex_correo   varchar(100)     
ex_calle    varchar(100)     
ex_numero   varchar(5)   
ex_colonia  varchar(100)     
ex_ciudad   varchar(100)     
ex_telefono varchar(15)  
ex_celular  varchar(15)  
ex_sexo int(11)  
ex_nacimiento   date     
ex_religion int(11)  
ex_ocupacion    varchar(100)     
ex_reco_id  int(11)  
Indices
PRIMARY ex_id
```

My updated query:

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE expedientes SET  `ex_nombre` = ?,
                                                            `ex_apaterno` = ?,
                                                            `ex_materno` = ?,
                                                            `ex_correo` = ?,
                                                            `ex_calle` = ?,
                                                            `ex_numero` = ?,
                                                            `ex_colonia` = ?,
                                                            `ex_ciudad` =?,
                                                            `ex_telefono` = ?,
                                                            `ex_celular` = ?,
                                                            `ex_sexo` = ?,
                                                            `ex_nacimiento` = ?,
                                                            `ex_religion` = ?,
                                                            `ex_ocupacion` = ?,
                                                            `ex_reco_id` = ?
                                                             WHERE `ex_id` = ?");

$stmt->bindparam('ssssssssssidisii',$nombre,$paterno,$materno,$umail,$calle,$numero,$colonia,$ciudad,$telefono,$celular,$sexo,$nacimiento,$religion,$ocupacion,$recomendado,$ex_id);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: I count 16 `?` and 17 variables bound. Have you checked?

Comment: Get rid of the `'ssssssssssidisii'` and it should work...

Comment: i count it again and still appear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `$stmt->bindparam` line and when you call the execute method do this instead:

```
$stmt->execute(array($nombre,$paterno,$materno,$umail,$calle,$numero,$colonia,$ciudad,$telefono,$celular,$sexo,$nacimiento,$religion,$ocupacion,$recomendado,$ex_id));
```

You were using bindParam incorrectly, the first parameter of bindParam does this:

> Parameter identifier. For a prepared statement using named placeholders, this will be a parameter name of the form :name. For a prepared statement using question mark placeholders, this will be the 1-indexed position of the parameter.  [Read more here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)

But with the execute method, the first parameter is this:

> An array of values with as many elements as there are bound parameters in the SQL statement being executed. All values are treated as PDO::PARAM_STR.  [Read more here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works fine